# How to create a table from a select statement in MySQL preserving encoding and DB engine

Tags: mysql

I have a table `foo` that's encoded utf8 and using innodb.  I want to create a table `bar` which is an exact copy of `foo`, however using the following:

```
  CREATE TABLE bar SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Results in a duplicate table, but set to the default encoding/DB engine of the database (in this case latin1).  Is there any way with this statement to preserve the settings of the table?  I know I could do the following:

```
 CREATE TABLE bar LIKE foo;
 INSERT INTO bar SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Just hoping there is a way to use the single statement shortcut.

Comment: Why not just set your default encoding to something sane like `utf8` rather than `latin1`?

Comment: @tadman some other tables might have other settings/needs and is not relevant to the question.  latin1 to utf8 is just an example, What if I had a specific collation needed on just that table and I just needed to copy the table?  Change my default collation for the entire DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `bar` to be an exact copy of `foo` then you should not use either of those shortcuts.

Using `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` you not only lose the `DEFAULT CHARSET` for your table, but also any indexes and foreign keys.

Using `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` preserver the `DEFAULT CHARSET` and the indexes for your table, but not the foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have FK constraints, but if I did, is there any way to preserve them ? (I'm assuming you mean forieign key constraints in this table related to other tables, not other tables with constraints on foo)

Comment: I guess there is no option and I should avoid the shorcut.  Thx.